# Why I can't see the background image in the device, but appears on the simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Here is the viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

It can show the simulator, but not on the device, why?? thz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also check that the image isn't a PSD named with a PNG extension. The Simulator can show PSD images, the device can't. :)

Comment: Got it! u got the point. Thz u very much, it waste me many time to find out that issue. Thz u!!

Answer (score 3):

The device is case-sensitive, so make sure you've got bg.png exactly right.

Comment: checked, still can't load the img.